# Definition of subobject in category theory?

Tags: category-theory

A subobject of $X$ in category theory is defined as a certain equivalence class of monomorphisms to $X$.

What I don’t understand about this definition, is that this doesn’t actually define an object in the category (as far as I know). It seems at first sight to me to be a type error? We are looking for an object, not an equivalence class of arrows? How does this define an object?

Comment: It shouldn't (or more precisely, it can't).  It's just a convenient name to harken back to subsets, subgroups, etc.

Comment: Technically you don't need objects as a separate class because you can use identity maps to identify objects; i.e., to each object there is an identity map and to each identity map there is an object. So you can just stick to the arrows, and that gives you all the information you need.

Comment: The name can be misleading but think of it like this, in the category $Sets$, each subobject is a subset(by our intuition) and it can be identified by its inclusion function. Now thinking of category theory as a "calculus of maps" sorta thing, having a subobject $X$ of $Y$ isn't enough we want to know also "how" it is a suboject and here the morphism becomes important.

Comment: The name is a bit misleading. The definition is very clear. A "subobject" is an **equivalence class**. Nowhere in the definition does it indicate that a "subobject" is an object of the category in question. It is a conveient name only. However, in many commonly known categories it **does** correspond to an object in the category, hence the name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object is the domain of the monomorphism; this is why IMO the correct definition should just be "a monomorphism," period. Taking equivalence classes doesn't buy you much, really.

If you haven't, it's worth working through special cases of this definition. In $\text{Set}$ you get subsets, in $\text{Grp}$ you get subgroups, and so on and so forth.

Comment: That you take equivalence classes seems kind of important for at least technical reasons. For example, for any non-empty set, there is a proper class of monomorphisms into it but only a set of subobjects. This is important, for example, for defining the $\mathsf{Sub}$ functor. Admittedly, this set of subobjects isn't *literally* the set of equivalence classes of monomorphisms as that would be a "set" of proper classes.

Comment: Shouldn't the definition of "A subobject of object $X$" be "an object that has a monomorphism to $X$"? Why is the monomorphism itself the subobject? (it's not even an object).

Comment: @user56834: no. Being a subobject is a structure, not a property. A given object $X$ may be a subobject of an object $Y$ in many different ways (consider e.g. the different ways a given group might be a subgroup of another group), and what those ways are are precisely (equivalence classes, if you like, of) monomorphisms from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: Similarly, a group itself is not just a set $G$, it's a set $G$ equipped with a multiplication $G \times G \to G$ satisfying axioms. A subobject isn't just an object, it's an object equipped with a monomorphism.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan These two comments were the answer I was looking for, thanks :)